# Writing information from a List of KeyValuePairs into a DataRow

Tags: c#

I have the following algorithm which retrieves information in a `List` of `KeyValuePair` (prices) and write them in a `DataRow`. I was wondering if I could achieve the same result without `j`.

```
if (prices != null)
{
   for (int i = 8, j=0; j < prices.Count; i+=2, j++) 
   {
      res[i] = prices[j].Value;
      res[i+1] = prices[j].Key;
   }
}
```

The ouput is a `DataRow` as follow :

```
res[8] = prices[0].Value
res[9] = prices[0].Key
res[10] = prices[1].Value
res[11] = prices[1].Key
res[12] = prices[2].Value
res[13] = prices[2].Key
```

etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can calculate `i` from `j` as `2*j + 8` (and `2*j + 9`). That would change your code to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < prices.Count; j++) 
{
   res[2*j + 8] = prices[j].Value;
   res[2*j + 9] = prices[j].Key;
}
```

Though I'm not sure whether this is actually better code than the original.

Comment: Well at least this answer my question perfectly. I dont know how I missed that however.

Answer (score 12):

I would approach this first by flattening the prices dictionary into a sequence of values eg `{ Key, Value, Key, Value, Key, Value }`.

```
// This method is returning object for now since I'm not clear what types are in your data row..
IEnumerable<object> Flatten<K, V>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>> pairs)
{
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        yield return pair.Value;
        yield return pair.Key;
    }
}
```

Using this I can simply loop over the flattened dictionary and copy the values into the data row:

```
int offset = 8;
foreach (var x in Flatten(prices))
{
    res[offset++] = x;
}
```

*I suspect there is a far better term than "flatten" for what I'm doing with the dictionary here.*

Comment: that looks a lot cleaner than what I was going to do.

Comment: The question says it's a list of key-value pairs, not a dictionary. (Though that will just mean that you would change the type of `pairs`.)

Comment: @svick good spot, changed to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`.

Comment: Though your answer is good I was looking for something like what svick did. Thanks anyway !

Comment: That is probably faster than the accepted answer because there is no arithmetic overhead. (Note: you need to yield `Value` before `Key` to conform OP's situation)

Comment: @ssg good spot, will update the answer. In my example the C# compiler will be generating a lot of [boilerplate code](http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Coding_Solutions%E2%80%94What_Does_Yield_Keyword_Generate) for me. Svicks solution should be quicker since simple integer arithmetic is effortless to the CPU - not to mention easier for the compiler to optimize. I think the main advantage of my solution is the re-usability of the `Flatten` method.